# Building cross-platform via cmake without Jenkins cmake plugin

Tags: c++, jenkins, cmake, continuous-integration

I was wondering how difficult it is to setup jenkins without the cmake jenkins plugin.

Currently I have a cmake build system (configured with CMakePresets.json) that builds with Visual Studio generator on windows, and with Ninja on linux

Is cmake plugin the only way, or can I call a command at a top level that reads my cmake configs and builds from that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way:

If you use CMakePresets.json, you can pass via cmdline to cmake command the -preset flag

You need newer versions of cmake 3.19 or higher

verify version with cmake --version